# Reimplementing sizeHintForColumn() to resizeColumnsToContents() over all cells (not only shown) in QTableView

Tags: pyqt

I am developing a PyQt application that has a QTableWidget, that could, potentially, be used to display a large amount of rows. I would like that each column width would be defined by the maximal element width of the whole column, not only by the largest element that is displayed at the moment of programmatical adding of cells data to the table widget.

The [Qt docs](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qtableview.html#resizeColumnToContents) in the resizeColumnToContents() method description state that

> Only visible columns will be resized.
> Reimplement [sizeHintForColumn()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qtableview.html#sizeHintForColumn) to
> resize hidden columns as well.

The question is, how exactly should I do this correctly? Unfortunately, I have no real experience in PyQt, and I was unable to find any sources of this method to give me any leads on how should I do this.

And is it possible to do resizing based on the current content displayed at any given moment, i.e. resize after any paintEvents recieved by the table widget?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to subclass QTableWidget and override the sizeHintForColumn method, returning an integer that describes the width in pixels you want.  You can calculate the width by using the `width` method of [QFontMetrics](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qfontmetrics.html) on the longest string.

```
class MyTable(QtGui.QTableWidget):

    def sizeHintForColumn(self, column):

        fm = self.fontMetrics()
        max_width = 0

        for i in range(self.rowCount()):

            width = fm.width(self.item(i,column).text()) + 10
            if  width > max_width:
                max_width = width

        return max_width
```

If you're going to be doing a lot of adding elements and calling `resizeColumnToContents` afterwards, you will probably want to store the result somehow.  That way you won't have to loop over all rows each time.

Comment: Thank you. I guess, I would have to create my QTableWidget as an instance of my class (MyTable here) (unfortunately, I can't check it myself ATM)? Is there any way to make this class compatible with Qt Designer or should I just complete the forms' design, compile the final version of .ui, and then manually edit the ui's .py file? The fact that QTableWidget is instantiated in an automatically-generated file that is not meant to be edited manually confused me the most.

Comment: The class you actually use in your program will probably inherit both QTableWidget and the class you designed in Qt Designer.  If that's the case, you can just stick the `sizeHintForColumn` method in your program's class.

Comment: Ah ok.  Sorry, I was thinking your Qt Designer class was just the TableWidget not the MainWindow.  In that case there are two ways to do it.  One is to edit the Qt Designer generated code to replace the line where your QTableWidget gets constructed with a line calling the new class as given above in my answer.  Another is to add your custom class to Qt Designer.  I've never done that, but I think it's straightforward.  See http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/designer.html#writing-qt-designer-plugins . It's probably much easier to just edit the code, though.

Comment: Thanks it works. But I loading big tables so do you think this solution is efficient ? What do you mean by saving result in a variable ?

Comment: In the case that items may have varying fonts, I would recommend instead of `fm = self.fontMetrics()` using `fm = QtGui.QFontMetrics(self.item(i,column).font())` . Placing it in the for loop before `width = ...` this will get the metrics for the individual QTableWidgetItem in lieu of the entire table.